# How can I use proxy with ssh2_sftp methods in PHP?

Tags: php, ssh2-sftp

I checked the docs but I can't find any reference to proxy usage for `ssh2_sftp` functions in PHP...

How can I use a proxy with those functions?

Comment: You can't. Although that said you're not gonna be able to use a lot of proxies with this. A SOCKSv4 or a SOCKSv5 or a HTTP CONNECT proxy, sure, but not a run of the mill HTTP proxy. My thought: maybe try http://phpseclib.sourceforge.net/ . That doesn't support proxying out of the box either but it is pure PHP so you modifying it would probably be a lot easier. You could ask for help on SO as well.

Comment: Tried PHPsecLib, with no success...

Comment: What'd you try? As I said, you'd need to modify phpseclib to work. Not even phpseclib is going to work out of the box.